# Run raspi-config non-interactively - skip whiptail dialogs

Tags: raspi-config

I'm running raspi-config on remote hosts non-interactively, using Ansible. Since there is no TTY attached, opening dialogs with `whiptail` will make the system get stuck.

Versions:

Debian: Bookworm

raspi-config: 20231216

As an example, when running raspi-config to configure the serial port:

```
sudo raspi-config nonint do_serial 0
```

...raspi-config will open a whiptail dialog:

[image]

Is it possible to prevent raspi-config from opening the dialog, so it can be non-interactively?

I had a look at the raspi-config source code but could not find anything related: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config

Comment: what about line 6 of raspi-config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you need to invoke `raspi-config` in a non-interactive mode is:

```bash
sudo raspi-config nonint <command>
```

A [list of commands is available](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#raspi-config-cli) in the "Official Documentation", and some caveats/warnings/etc re use of the *non-interactive* option.

***However***, there is no `do_serial` option listed; there are `do_serial_hw` and `do_serial_cons` options - but no `do_serial`. And so I **suspect** that the *ncurses gui* for `raspi-config` has been called because your chosen option doesn't exist.

Comment: As you see in my question I'm running the command with `nonint` already, but its still showing the dialog. When running the command remotely without a TTY, it will get stuck.

Comment: @Wolkenarchitekt: I am connected to my RPi 5 (running 'bookworm') via SSH. I enter this command, and it executes from the CLI without bringing up the _ncurses GUI_: `sudo raspi-config nonint do_hostname raspberrypi5`. Try that - just to validate the theory that I've advanced in the edit to my answer.

Comment: Ok, looks like do_serial is kind of undocumented, and also does not consider nonint like the other documented commands. So its kind of a bug.
Running commands with nonint still seems to be the answer somehow, so accepting